# Non-boolean monotone planar circuit value problem

Tags: circuit-complexity

It is known that monotone planar boolean circuits have a NC circuit value problem (in fact, [much more is known](http://www.cse.iitb.ac.in/~nutan/papers/mpcvp-cc.pdf)).

What about **non-boolean monotone planar** circuits?

Precisely, take $Q=\{0,...,n-1\}$ and any family of monotone functions $f_i:Q^2\rightarrow Q$ and consider planar circuits where gates are chosen among the $f_i$. What is known for such circuits?

Comment: I don't think anyone studied this problem. I guess that the MPCVP algorithms for the binary case can be modified in a simple way when the size of Q is constant (by making a more elaborate interval structure). However, if Q is allowed to vary with the input size it seems that the problem is P complete, by having alternate levels of Q representing true and false.